# What would be the easiest way to do a Nav like this?

Tags: css, navigation, hover

I can't figure out how to make a Navigation like this:

http://www.andertons.co.uk/

The hover is disjointed almost from the main nav. Any ideas / tips how i'd accomplish this?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="naviItem">
    Games
    <ul>
        <li>Game 1</li>
        <li>Game 1</li>
        <li>Game 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.naviItem ul {
    display: none;
}

.naviItem:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should of been more clear :p I can make a dropdown however the bit I'm stuck on is how to make the hover effect on the main category look disjointed. E.g. if you hover over guitars it changes to white and the arrow is red but it's also ontop of the nav

Comment: @user1584964: I am sorry, but I do not understand, what you are talking about :(

Comment: http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/8548/menuco.png - You see how it overlaps the blue menu bar and the height of the hover is greater than the menu bar. I need to know how to do that!

Comment: I did not hack into the source code, but this is how you could do it: The main menu is actually bigger than it appears leaving enough space to let the hover background go over the edges. On hover a background is applied to the menu items that starts outside of the main menu and has a like 50% transperency. You will need to use CSS3 for that.

Comment: Hmmm not really sure what you mean?